# iwlwifi problems. Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5

Tags: networking, kde, iwlwifi

My wifi keeps dropping on my Laptop running Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (with the KDE desktop). After updating sometimes this gets better sometimes it gets much worse. The error given in the /var/log/syslog file it tells me:

```
Nov 21 10:43:15 Sangeya kernel: [  567.889186] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
Nov 21 10:43:21 Sangeya kernel: [  573.869538] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
Nov 21 10:43:21 Sangeya kernel: [  573.869650] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Error sending STATISTICS_CMD: enqueue_hcmd failed: -5
Nov 21 10:43:21 Sangeya kernel: [  573.888009] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Failed to wake NIC for hcmd
...
```

This only seems to happen on my home network and not at work. Though all other devices tested don't have issues at home.

Things seem to work for an hour or so after I reboot and then I get the same shutdown of networking.

I have tried googling this a lot, to no avail. How can I fix this or are there any logs/error messages that would be helpful in debugging this more?

Some extra info:

The output of the cmd `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface                                                       
       product: Wireless 3165                                                                
       vendor: Intel Corporation                                                             
       physical id: 0                                                                        
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0                                                            
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 79
       serial: 30:24:32:4d:4e:e1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-70-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 ip=192.168.1.10 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:147 memory:d5000000-d5001fff
```

The output of `rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
```